# Magento 2.2.2 does not load store properly and admin url through 404

Tags: php, magento2.2.2

Please help me with magento 2.2 installation issue.I have paid two days but no luck.

**following are my system specs:** 
 - 
 - Magento : 2.2.2

- PHP: 7.1.11-0ubuntu0.17.10.1 (cli) (built: Nov 1 2017 16:30:52) ( NTS )
- MySQL: 5.7.20
- Server version: Apache/2.4.27 (Ubuntu), Server built: 2017-09-18T15:05:48

**etc/php/7.1/php.ini :**

- mode_rewrite enabled
- max_execution_time = 1800
- max_input_time = 1800
- memory_limit = 2048M
- upload_max_filesize = 2048M
- max_file_uploads = 2048

A fresh installation with sample data is succeeded but my store is not loading properly (seems js/css not loading) and other links (about us, contact us etc) returns 404 **admin URL also returns 404 as well**.

I have used almost everything

- 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost for store and admin url
- changed app/etc/di.xml (Symlink to Copy) removed everything from pub/static except .htaccess
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
- php bin/magento cache:flush
- php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: Run this, and try again INSERT INTO 'core_config_data' ('path', 'value') VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;

Comment: Also try to add index.php

Comment: Check if you have a .htaccess file in your magento root. Also check if modrewrite is enabled in apache. And check if pub/static has content after static-content deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Seems global issue:

try the to do in the answer in this link

[Right Configuration after Install Magento2.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209128/magento-2-2-2-problem-with-php-bin-magento-setupdicompile/209331#209331)